# 415 Jersey JSON Java

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

Already tried many 'resolutions' I have found here and in others sites, but no one worked. My service is giving `415 Unsuported Media Type`.

Here is my [code](http://pastebin.com/mXbnxV36):

### service

```
package br.com.fusionconsultoria.services;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import br.com.fusionconsultoria.daos.DAOZFIT005;

@Path("/Authentication")
public class SERVICEZFIT000 {
    /*
     * @POST
     * 
     * @Produces("application/json")
     * 
     * @Consumes("application/json") public Response
     * authenticateUser(BEANCredential credentials) {
     * 
     * String username = credentials.getUsername(); String password =
     * credentials.getPassword();
     */
    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response authenticateUser(@FormParam("username") String username, @FormParam("password") String password) {
        try {
            // Authenticate the user using the credentials provided
            boolean login = authenticate(username, password);
            if (login == true) {
                // Issue a token for the user
                String token = issueToken(username);
                // Save the token in DB
                DAOZFIT005 fiveDAO = new DAOZFIT005();
                boolean update = fiveDAO.updateZITOKEN(username, token);
                if (update == true) {
                    // Return the token on the response
                    return Response.ok(token).build();
                } else {
                    return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
                }
            } else {
                return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
        }
    }

    private boolean authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        DAOZFIT005 fiveDAO = new DAOZFIT005();
        boolean login = fiveDAO.login(username, password);
        return login;
    }

    private String issueToken(String username) {
        Random random = new SecureRandom();
        String token = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
        return token;
    }
}
```

### bean

```
package br.com.fusionconsultoria.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class BEANCredential implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String token;

    public String getToken() {
        return token;
    }

    public void setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>InBettaWS</groupId>
    <artifactId>InBettaWS</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-debug-all</artifactId>
            <version>6.0_ALPHA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.22.0-CR1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-b03</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-m05</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0-b170201.1204</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.26-b02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0-b35</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.Alpha1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InBettaWS</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>br.com.fusionconsultoria.filters, br.com.fusionconsultoria.daos, br.com.fusionconsultoria.services, br.com.fusionconsultoria.beans, br.com.fusionconsultoria.annotations, com.jersey.jaxb, com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InBettaWS</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In the service, have some lines commented 'cause I tried both situation, `URLECONDED` and `APPLICATION/JSON` in `@Consumes`

[Arc Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ET3zN.png)

***EDIT:***
I found the problem of the `415`, it was in ARC, I was doing a type not declared in my Service.
But now, the `username` and `password` is getting null, is anything with my `x-www-urlencoded` ?

Comment: Please post the "client" code (ie. the code performing the login post)

Comment: @RC Im using `ARC Google Chrome Plugin` to test the  service. I edited the post with a print

Comment: @Carol You are using `@FormParam` annotation for receiving user name and password. But in the image, you are sending them in Authorization header. It can not map. That is why, these values are null